# NextJS checking for values in an array from SWR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have an API endpoint that returns an ID, but also a list of tenants and also a list of invites as arrays.

What I want to do is if there are any invites, i want to render them out in an

list, and then if there are any tenants i would also like to render them out in

element, but if there are neither (blank arrays) i want it to just say 'no results found'

The API returns the data as follows;

```
array:1 [▼
  "data" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => "9996c84f-3089-4b83-95d1-001541267106"
      "tenants" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:5 [▼
          "id" => "9996c84f"
          "user_id" => "c0394d51ee57"
        ]
      ]
      "invites" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:5 [▼
          "id" => "9996c84f"
          "property_id" => "001541267106"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

In my Next project, i get the data from the endpoint using;

```
const { data: tenants, error: tenanterror, mutate: tenantmutate } = useSWR('/tenants', () =>
    axios.get('/tenants')
        .then(response => response.data.data)
)
```

When i try and render anything using;

```
{tenants.tenants.id}
```

It just doesnt return anything at all

Comment: If it's an array you need to access with indexes, not keys. Have you tried it? Like `tenants[0].id` etc